# T SQL Group column with accumulating data in one record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a query on SQL Server to merge data items in 1 record

**Input table:**

```
sales_ref_no    Description
001 Hello
001 Hi
002 Dear
002 All
002 Please
003 Thanks
```

**Output table:**

```
sales_ref_no    Description
001 Hello | Hi
002 Dear | All | Please
003 Thanks
```

The description under the same sales_ref_no is accumulated under the same record using a | delimiter

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: try to google sql server string aggregation. There're a lot of answer on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select 
  sales_ref_no,
  STUFF((
  SELECT ' | ' + B.Description
   FROM YOUR_TABLE B
   WHERE (B.sales_ref_no = A.sales_ref_no) 
   FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,2,'') AS Description
From YOUR_TABLE A
Group By sales_ref_no
```